# Доступ к сервису на localhost из docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

У меня redis сервер работает на 127.0.0.1:6380 моей локальной машины. Приложение в докере развенуто с помощью docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
         - "8087:8000"
    environment:
#      - CACHE_REDIS_HOST=redis
    depends_on:
#      - redis

#  redis:
#    image: redis:latest
#    ports:
#      - "6379:6379"
```

Вопрос, могу ли я как-то сделать, чтобы приложение видело локальный редис. Потому что сейчас выдает ошибку

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6380. 111.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполни команду `ip a` или `ipconfig`(windows) и смотри интерфейс докера

```
~$ ip a
......
11: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:82:d6:63:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
.....
```

172.17.0.1 - адрес для подключения к локалхосту.

Также доступно имя `host.docker.internal` - вставляй вместо localhost